# Use Button to Open Contacts to Retrieve Phone Number and Print to String

Tags: android, string, onclick, contacts

So I do some android development on and off, and right now I'm a bit rusty.

Basically all I want to do is have the user press a button and then that brings them to choose a contact, and then that prints that to a string.

I have onCick running as such `@Override
            public void onClick(View paramView) {
                Main.this.phone = Main.this`

with other things attached to it. So how would I load contacts as I expect to. I can provide more information as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern should be:

onClick() {

intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

intent.setData(null);

intent.setType(null);

startActivityForResult(intent,0);

}

onActivityResult(int requestcode, int resultcode, Intent returnIntent) {

Uri resultUri = returnIntent.getData();

}

The intent you send out will cause the contacts app to display a picker, from which the user can choose a contact. The content URI of that contact is returned to you in onActivityResult(), in another intent. You can use that to look for data for that particular contact.

Comment: Um, aren't you missing `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` or something? Your `Intent` does not state from what you want to pick.

Comment: I was thinking very similar Commons, I have seen a little bit of code on accessing contacts, I just cant seem to implement it properly.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you need Contacts.CONTENT_URI.